Postgres 13, patroni и Wal
Была задача скопировать данные из одной таблицы в другую.
Выполнил на мастере следующий запрос:
INSERT INTO mt_doc_abstractgeoobject_temp (id,
tenant_id,
data,
mt_last_modified,
mt_version,
mt_dotnet_type,
ebg_node_id,
parent_id,
standardized_name,
localized_name,
object_type,
mt_doc_type,
mt_deleted,
mt_deleted_at,
url_name,
priority_hotel,
priority_main,
priority_tour,
url_name_static) 
SELECT * from mt_doc_abstractgeoobject;

После того как запрос отработал на мастере сгенерировалось большое кол-во wal файлов. По прошествии 12 часов эти валы так и не разошлись (на реплике они тоже есть). В логах нет никаких ошибок, чекпоинт срабатывает и некоторые вал файлы все же отправляются на отдельную машину. Лага репликации нет. Реплика асинхронная. Что можно сделать что бы эти валы всё же отправились хранится на отдельную машину и постгрес вычистил у себя каталог с pg_wal ?

как задать хороший вопрос

Добавлю: Подвисших сессий нет

если под "отправились хранится на отдельную машину" вы имеете в виду archive_command - то напишите об этом. Что в логах базы? Какая именно archive_command с точки зрения выведет ли она какую-то ошибку в случае собственно ошибки, может быть программа вызываемая в вашем archive_command ведёт отдельно свой лог?

Проблема была решена.
Была допущена ошибка в конфигурации. Установлен postgres 13.
В конфиге присутствовал параметр wal_keep_segments: 5120
Этот параметр был переименован в wal_keep_size и установлено значение в 5GB.
После рестарта кластера все вал файлы были пушнуты и удалены из pg_wal
